# y_pred = regressor.predict(sc_X.transform(6.5)) not working

Tags: python, spyder

Whenever I am going to predict, I see an error. 
I am stuck with the line `y_pred = regressor.predict(6.5)` in the code.

I am getting the error:

> ValueError: Expected 2D array, got scalar array instead:
>   array=6.5.
>   Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.

spyder

```
# SVR

# Importing the libraries

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# Importing the dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv('Position_Salaries.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, 1:2].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, 2].values


# Feature Scaling
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc_X = StandardScaler()
sc_y = StandardScaler()
X = sc_X.fit_transform(X)
y = sc_y.fit_transform(y)

# Fitting SVR to the dataset
from sklearn.svm import SVR
regressor = SVR(kernel = 'rbf')
regressor.fit(X, y)

# Predicting a new result
y_pred = regressor.predict(6.5)
```

Error:  y_pred = regressor.predict(sc_X.transform(6.5))

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-11-64bf1bca4870>", line 1, in <module>
    y_pred = regressor.predict(sc_X.transform(6.5))

  File "C:\Users\achiever\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\data.py", line 758, in transform
    force_all_finite='allow-nan')

  File "C:\Users\achiever\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 514, in check_array
    "if it contains a single sample.".format(array))

ValueError: Expected 2D array, got scalar array instead: array=6.5. Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

Comment: Buddy, without data sample, all this effort is futile. What are the dimensions of X? Surely, it is supposed to be a 2D array.

Comment: Your line in the code is `y_pred = regressor.predict(6.5)` but the error says `y_pred = regressor.predict(sc_X.transform(6.5))`

Answer (score 0):

Well, obviously, since regressor.predit() expects a list/array of values to make a prediction of, and you're passing it a single float, it won't work:

```
# Predicting a new result
y_pred = regressor.predict(6.5)
```

At the very least :

```
# Predicting a new result
y_pred = regressor.predict(np.array([6.5]))
```

But presumably you have more stuff you want to pass to it, so more like:

```
# Predicting a new result
y_pred = regressor.predict(some_data_array)
```

EDIT:

you need to arrange the shape of the 2d array you pass to the predictor so it looks like this:

data = [[1,0,0,1],[0,1,12,5],....]

where [1,0,0,1] is ONE set of parameter for ONE datapoint for which you want a prediction. [0,1,12,5) it ANOTHER data point.

At any rate, they should all have the same # of feature (e.g. 4 in my example) and they should have the same number of features as the data you used to train your predictor.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I did that, still Nothing happens.

Comment: try `y_pred = regressor.predict(np.array([6.5]).reshape(-1,1)`

Comment: It still gives me error:

y_pred = regressor.predict(np.array([6.5]).reshape(-1,1)

  File "<ipython-input-26-3c983ba7ad40>", line 1
    y_pred = regressor.predict(np.array([6.5]).reshape(-1,1)
                                                            ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Comment: @SOUVIKDATTA: we don't have your data. I've no idea how many features (parameters) in your data you have, so I can't tell you exactly how you need to format your code. Either post sample data or figure out how to format it yourself.

But basically, the shape of some_data_array needs to be (number_of_sample_to_predict, number_of_parameters_in_data)

Comment: That last error means you file is formated wrong. That's another problem/unrelated matter. I suggest you test these things independantly (e.g. open your file & read it properly, etc.). Otherwise we're just trying to navigate in a mess of bugs and we can't tell what's causing what issue.

Comment: But in your code, X = [:, 1:2].... what happens to index 0? I think you need to think harder about what your data is and what you need to access in it.

Comment: my data is simple. It has three columns. column2 is x and column 3 is y: x=1:10; y= any 10 values. Column 1 contains only names what is not needed here. Thank you.

Comment: @Francky: This worked. Thank you for your valuable time.
y_pred = regressor.predict(sc_X.transform([[6.5]]))

Comment: Unexpected EOF while parsing was probably due to the missing parentheses, like I had in my comment...

Answer (score 0):

```
y_pred = sc_Y.inverse_transform(regressor.predict(sc_X.transform(np.array([[6.5]]))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use reshape function:

```
sc_y.inverse_transform(regressor.predict(sc_X.transform([[6.5]])).reshape(1,-1))
```